# Storing Utc Time in Getter/Setter Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Currently, I am storing the`DateTime` with the `DeliveryDate` getter/setter. However, I'm having issues storing this in **UTC** time. I've done some research on this and tried `DateTimeKind.Utc` but can't get that to work correctly. **How can I get `DeliveryDate` to store the DateTime in UTC time?**

**My Code:**

```
public partial class shippingInfo
{
    public System.Guid EmailConfirmationId {get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeliveryDate {get; set; }
}
```

**Update: Added Implementation:**

```
 DeliveryExpirationRepository.Add(new DeliveryPendingConfirmation
 {
     EmailConfirmationId = newGuid,
     DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(48),
 });
```

Comment: It all depends on the code that generates the `DateTime` object that will be assigned to `DeliveryDate`. That is the code you need to show.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain just added the implementation. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to convert to time into UTC and with the getter convert it from UTC to another timezone?

Comment: @MartijnvanPut no, I just want to store it in **UTC** time. I don't need to convert it to anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a `DateTime` store a UTC value, you must assign it a UTC value. Note the use of `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`:

```
DeliveryExpirationRepository.Add(new DeliveryPendingConfirmation
{
    EmailConfirmationId = newGuid,
    DeliveryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(48),
});
```

The [`DateTime.UtcNow` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Gets a `DateTime` object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

The [`DateTime.Now` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Gets a `DateTime` object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time.

You might want to use [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. It always stores an absolute point in time, unambiguously.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyShields for your answer. On the `DateTimeOffset. Would that look something like `DeliveryDate = `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(48)`.....

Comment: @CodeChaser No, I was suggesting that you simply make the type of your `DeliveryDate` property `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>`, which can never be ambiguous.  The user of the property can decide whether they want to show that `DateTimeOffset` as UTC or local time (for some time zone) and never have to worry about if they're making a time zone mistake with the date calculations. `DateTime` doesn't necessarily have that comfort property.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Thanks again!... By the way, nice profile pic! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a code to the setter method to check if value is not in UTC and convert this value to UTC:

```
public class shippingInfo {
    public System.Guid EmailConfirmationId { get; set; }
    private Nullable<System.DateTime> fDeliveryDate;
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeliveryDate {
        get { return fDeliveryDate; }
        set {
            if (value.HasValue && value.Value.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc) {
                fDeliveryDate = value.Value.ToUniversalTime();
            }
            else {
                fDeliveryDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, you don't need to care how a value of this property is set. Or you can use the DateTime.ToUniversalTime method to convert any date to UTC where you set a value of the property.